# Skipping Numbers Using a Counter

Tags: counters

I have several counters in my document, defined as follows:

`\newcounter{koala}
\newcommand*\koala[1][]{\refstepcounter{koala}\textbf{\thekoala #1} }
\setcounter{koala}{0}`

I know that I can start the counter at any number I like by using the `\setcounter` command.

However, in my document I need to skip a series of numbers. For example I will start with 1, 2, 3, 4, but then need to jump to 23, 24, 25 etc.

Is there a simple command(s) that will add a specific number to the counter so this can be achieved?

Comment: Use `\seccounter` again when you want to start from a new number. This may "cost as much as" what you want actually.

Comment: Thanks. However, I wish to add a specific number. For example if my numbering was 1, 2, 3, 23, 24, 25, if I then added in '4', I would like the numbering to become 1, 2, 3, 4, 24, 25, 26.

Comment: use more times!

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek’s answer is, perhaps, even too elaborate: the short answer is: yes, there is a simple command that adds a specific number to  counter, and it is named `\addtocounter`… ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If the counter is only incremented by macro `\koala`, then the skipping can be put there:

```
\newcommand*\koala[1][]{%
  \ifnum4=\value{koala}%
    \addtocounter{koala}{18}%
  \fi
  \refstepcounter{koala}%
  \textbf{\thekoala #1}%
}
```

An alternative approach is to manipulate the counter at the formatting level:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thekoala}{%
  \ifnum\value{koala}>4 %
    \@arabic{\numexpr\value{koala} + 18\relax}%
  \else
    \arabic{koala}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

With this approach, `\value{koala}` is incremented continuously, but `\thekoala` jumps.